# Excel VBA - Search certain column for a #N/A, copy entire row to new sheet and delete row

Tags: vba, excel

This is what I have already. It searches column B  in sheet 1 for #N/A and deletes the row.

```
Sub DeleteErrorRows()
    On Error Resume Next    
    Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 16).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0     
End Sub
```

What I would like is for it to copy that row onto sheet 2 and then delete? So I can have a record of what was deleted.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub DeleteErrorRows()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 16).EntireRow
    r.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    r.Delete
End Sub
```